# Match each variable passed in MYSQL IN()

Tags: mysql, function, select, join

Basically I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.ID, users.name
FROM users 
INNER JOIN usersSkills ON users.ID = usersSkills.userID 
INNER JOIN usersLanguages ON users.ID = usersLanguages.userID 
WHERE activated = "1" 
AND type = "GRADUATE" 
AND usersSkills.skillID IN(2, 21)
AND usersLanguages.languageID IN(2, 22)
```

I need to match the skillID and languageID to each parameter passed in the IN() function at the moment on each of those it will serve up a result if either parameter is found.

So essentially i want to only see results if the skill ID of 2 AND 21 are found on the skills table and the same idea for the languages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a GROUP BY (this will also eliminate the need for SELECT DISTINCT) to get an aggregate count and a HAVING clause to make sure the count of distinct elements returned matches the number of elements you're searching for.

```
SELECT users.ID, users.name
FROM users 
INNER JOIN usersSkills ON users.ID = usersSkills.userID 
INNER JOIN usersLanguages ON users.ID = usersLanguages.userID 
WHERE activated = "1" 
AND type = "GRADUATE" 
AND usersSkills.skillID IN(2, 21)
AND usersLanguages.languageID IN(2, 22)
GROUP BY users.ID, users.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT usersSkills.skillID) = 2
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT usersLanguages.languageID) = 2
```

Comment: Thank That's pretty close but I am still getting the following error: Unknown column 'usersLanguages.languageID' in 'having clause

Comment: @AndréFigueira Check for typos.

Comment: I have and it's correct, The one you posted was missing an s but i fixed that and it still not working

Comment: Manasged to get it working now sorry since i was trying to get this to render dynamically one of the ands was rendering in the wrong place causing erratic results, thank you soooo much been working on this all day :(

Comment: @AndréFigueira Glad to help. Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it.